# What does "girls of the world" refer to in this context?

Tags: lyrics, african-american-vernacular-english

In the 1986 rap song "Girls Ain't Nothing but Trouble" by "DJ Jazzy Jeff & The Fresh Prince", the lyrics go like this:

> Listen, homeboys, don't mean to bust your bubble
> But **girls of the world** ain't nothing but trouble

Full lyrics: https://genius.com/Dj-jazzy-jeff-and-the-fresh-prince-girls-aint-nothing-but-trouble-lyrics

Where it's said/sung/rapped in the music video: https://youtu.be/IOaFh-yJk_k?t=18

What does "girls of the world" mean? Is it just a convoluted way to say "girls" or "females" in general? Or does it refer to "girls of the world" as in "girls who are worldly" or something? And if so, what does *that* mean? It's not at all obvious to me what "girls of the world" means, and I suspect that it might be some kind of "Ebonics" slang which I haven't learned.

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but those "girls of the world" words have repeated in my head regularly for many years now. I need to get "closure".

Comment: Since word choice in songs is often driven by rhythm or melody, I suspect that the only person that could definitively answer with the intended meaning is the writer or writers of the lyric.

Comment: From [*woman of the world*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woman%20of%20the%20world): "a woman who has had many experiences and who is not shocked by things that may be shocking to other people." *Girls* would mean the same thing as *woman*. Whether that makes sense in relation to the lyrics themselves is a matter of interpretation.